# Conducting wire covered by a paramagnetic dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

How does the conductance of a conducting wire change if it is covered by a paramagnetic material comparing to a diamagnetic one? I am interested in the  DC or low frequencies response mainly.

For me it is not obvious, sorry. And that is why - roughness of the surface in the conducting channel of a transistor cause additional elastic scatterings that has effect on carrier mobility, conductance. As a result, threshold and DC characteristics of the transistor depend on it. The roughness can be caused by the trap states accumulating static electric charge distributed over the surface. What if instead of the charge, we have spins distributed around the channel? Does coupling between those spins and the current  change conductance of the channel? I can reformulate it as follows: there are charge sensors, where excess charge  changes the current; are there analogous sensor where excess spin changes the current?

Comment: Typically a dielectric causes losses or delays at high frequencies. This affects sharp pulses by lowering their fronts and has significant practical consequences, both bad and good. The effect depends a lot on the dielectric constant, so typically materials are used with a low constant of around 2, unless in ceramic capacitors where it may be in thousands. I am saying all this, because your question can be easily misunderstood as about DC and wrongly classified. You should qualify "conductance" as either "of short pulses" or "at various frequencies", if you hope for a good answer.

Comment: I have edited the question. So I am interested in DC response mainly. The question is about interaction between current and spin-polarizable media.

Comment: Assuming the covering material is nonconductive, it won't affect the conductor at DC. But this answer is so obvious that I suspect I am not understanding the intent of your question, really. Maybe you should clarify what you are *really* thinking about.

Comment: There is a static field interaction, but no energy transfer at DC, so no change in the current. You need to clarify what your motivation is.

Comment: What about attraction of two wires with DC current? They do mechanical work, don't they?